# Facebook Graph API unable to get profile_pic from the list of comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Getting this comment listing (without profile_pic) works:

```
.../(page-post-id)/comments?fields=from{first_name,last_name},message
```

Getting this comment listing (with profile_pic) doesn't work:

```
.../(page-post-id)/comments?fields=from{first_name,last_name,profile_pic},message
```

Expected Behaviour:

In comment listing, able to get profile_pic of the user who posted the comment

Actual Behaviour:

In comment listing, once profile_pic is explicitly specified, the entire comment disappear from the listing

This API is called using page access token, on a page post owned by that page. Comments are left by page admins, and admin of the app that generated the page access token.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem, and after a lot of searching, I eventually ended up solving it.

Use the field `picture` instead of `profile_pic`.

I think the documentation is not updated because it says that the field `from` will return a `User`, linking to a page where we can find the `profile_pic` filed.